# How to prove $\vdash p\to\neg\neg p$ in this system?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was asked to prove $\vdash p\to\neg\neg p$ in this system.

> Axioms:
>   $(\mathcal A_1)\vdash p\to(q\to p)$
>   $(\mathcal A_2)\vdash (p\to(q\to r))\to((p\to q)\to (p\to r))$
>   $(\mathcal A_3)\vdash \neg\neg p\to p$

I have tried to use axiom 2 and find a proper proposition $x$ such that $\vdash (p\to(x\to\neg\neg p)) \to ((p\to x)\to (p\to \neg\neg p))$ holds, but I couldn't find one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note from a comment on a deleted answer: there is also a rule that $\lnot P$ may be replaced by $P \to \bot$.

Comment: For a system like this, trying to solve individual propositional expressions is like trying to build a house with a blindfold on.  You should first learn truth tables, then translate the process of proving something with truth tables into the language of this logic.  This is usually hidden as a "proof of completeness".  Figuring out how to solve every propositional expression is much much easier than figuring out how to solve 1 propositional expression.

Comment: If modus ponens is the only rule of inference, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.. I've known how to solve this — by employing the Deduction Theorem:

> If $A$ is a set of propositions, $p$, $q$ are propositions, then $A \vdash p\to q$ is equivalent to $A \cup \{p\} \vdash q$.

**Proof**

$$\{p,\neg p\}\vdash p\tag{1; assumed}$$
$$\{p,\neg p\}\vdash \neg p=(p\to\bot)\tag{2; assumed}$$
$$\{p,\neg p\}\vdash \bot\quad\tag{3; MP,1,2}$$
$$\{p\}\vdash (\neg p\to \bot)=\neg\neg p\tag{4; DT}$$
$$\vdash (p\to \neg\neg p)\tag{5; DT}$$

Comment: This is correct.  You might want to replace F with $\bot$ for clarity since F looks like a propositional variable.  Also you can use \tag to name expressions.